# What unpowered bladed tool can make deep beveled cuts in sheet material?

Tags: tools, cutting

I can use a tablesaw the bevel the edges of a sheet of material.

I can use a circular saw or jig saw with a bevel attachment to make similar cuts in the middle of the sheet instead of the edges. If I use a jig saw, those cuts can turn and curve.

I would like to make similar cuts to what a jig saw can make, but in less hard material and with razor blades instead of a powered saw. My target depth is about 1 inch, so something that uses standard trapezoidal box cutter blades would be appropriate.

Is there a tool that can do this?

Mat board cutters come close, but they seem to generally only do one or two specific angles, and I haven't found one that can make non-straight cuts.

Comment: how about making a jig to hold the blade that would turn it into an oversized mat cutter? Are you cutting foam board or something?

Comment: Model railroading? If you're cutting foam boards of some sort, consider using a hot-wire cutter.

Comment: @DaveTweed the sheets are too big for any hot wire cutter's arm, and even if I replace the blade with a hot wire, I still need a device to hold the wire at the appropriate angle while I move it.

Comment: @Sparr What is the material you're looking to cut?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk foam that can be easily cut with a razor blade

Answer (score 1):

You could make some utility or razor blade holders from wood. Saw a rectanglular block down the length at the desired bevel angle, clean up with a hand plane, then clamp the blade in the centre using predrilled screws, from both sides.

You can then use it by drawing it against a fence, either plunging like the mat cutters or starting from the edge of the material.

It would be inexpensive to make a few standard angles; you could extend the range by placing thin shims along the part closest to the fence to achieve steeper intermediary angles.